# Emacs - switch paragraphs with each other

Tags: emacs, org-mode, paragraphs

I'm looking for a solution which is already possible in Org-mode with headlines, example:

```
* HL1
* HL2 {press: Meta+arrowup}
```

=>

```
* HL2
* HL1
```

(1) I want to switch paragraphs like that. The idea is basically that I move the point somewhere {example: here []} in the middle of a paragraph, press {key+arrowdown} and the paragraph will be switched with the next one beneath.

(2) This would make it easier to restructure text while editing papers.

=> Paragraph (2) should be in front of paragraph (1) now.
I am not sure if this is a trivial problem.
It would be more suitable if it's ***not*** just a function like:

- Mark paragraph P1
- Copy
- move point beneath P2
- paste P1

A real switching of P1 and P2 wouldn't mess up spacings around the paragraphs.

Thanks,

**Edit: Solution found:**

1.easy:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-ü") 'transpose-paragraphs) ;; forward
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-ü")
                (lambda () (interactive) (transpose-paragraphs -1)
      (backward-paragraph)
    )) ;; backwards
```

2.elaborated (found in `ergoemacs-functions.el` - currently only `org-mode`):

```
(defmacro ergoemacs-define-org-meta (direction &optional disable)
  "Defines org-mode meta-direction keys.
DIRECTION defines the `org-mode' and `ergoemacs-mode' direction.
DISABLE defines if the option should be disabled by default."
  `(progn
     (defcustom ,(intern (format "ergoemacs-use-ergoemacs-meta%s" direction)) ,(not disable)
       ,(format "Use ergoemacs-mode defined <M-%s>." direction)
       :type 'boolean
       :group 'ergoemacs-mode)
     (defun ,(intern (format "ergoemacs-org-meta%s" direction))  ()
       ,(format "Run `org-meta%s' in the proper context.
When `ergoemacs-use-ergoemacs-meta%s' is non-nil use what ergoemacs-mode defines for <M-%s>.
ARG is the prefix argument for either command." direction direction direction)
       (interactive)
       (cond
        ((or
          (not ,(intern (format "ergoemacs-use-ergoemacs-meta%s" direction)))
          (org-at-heading-p)
          (org-at-item-p)
          (org-at-table-p)
          (and (org-region-active-p)
               (save-excursion
                 (goto-char (region-beginning))
                 (org-at-item-p)))
          (org-with-limited-levels
           (or (org-at-heading-p)
               (and (org-region-active-p)
                    (save-excursion
                      (goto-char (region-beginning))
                      (org-at-heading-p))))))
         ;; (setq prefix-arg current-prefix-arg)
         ;; Send prefix to next function
         (call-interactively ',(intern (format "org-meta%s" direction))))
        (t
         ;; (setq prefix-arg current-prefix-arg)
         ;; Send prefix to next function
         (ergoemacs-lookup-key-and-run ,(format "<M-%s>" direction)))))))
(ergoemacs-define-org-meta "left")
(ergoemacs-define-org-meta "right")
(ergoemacs-define-org-meta "up" t)
(ergoemacs-define-org-meta "down" t)
```

please confirm working!

Comment: Remove the `switch-statement` tag. This has nothing to do with it.

Comment: And add the `org-mode` tag.

Comment: No need to be sorry, you haven't offended me. Also, if the answer below (or any other answer that might be posted later) is helpful, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## transpose-paragraphs

`transpose-paragraphs` sounds like the function you want.  It's `interactive`, so you can invoke it with `M-x`.  If you find you need it a lot, consider binding it to a key (perhaps `M-T`?).

### Edit (summary of discussion following)

User lpoik found that, on his/her system, `transpose-paragraphs` with a argument of `-1` was not leaving `point` in the correct position (between the two paragraphs) for a subsequent repeat of the operation to move the paragraph up one more.  The workaround arrived at is to move point using `backward-paragraph` afterwards:

```
(defun my-transpose-paragraphs-backward ()
  (interactive "*")
  (transpose-paragraphs -1)
  (backward-paragraph))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-ü") 'my-transpose-paragraphs-backward)
```

I don't know whether this also works if you make `my-transpose-paragraphs-backward` accept a numeric argument:

```
(defun my-transpose-paragraphs-backward (arg)
  (interactive "*p")
  (transpose-paragraphs (- arg))
  (backward-paragraph))
```

Comment: This looks great so far! thanks!
The file contains following code: 

`(defun transpose-paragraphs (arg)
  "Interchange the current paragraph with the next one.
With prefix argument ARG a non-zero integer, moves the current
paragraph past ARG paragraphs, leaving point after the current paragraph.
If ARG is positive, moves the current paragraph forwards, if
ARG is negative moves it backwards.  If ARG is zero, exchanges
the current paragraph with the one containing the mark."
  (interactive "*p")
  (transpose-subr 'forward-paragraph arg))`

If I want to transpose backwards, I need to modify ARG?

Comment: lpoik: e.g. `M-- M-x transpose-paragraphs` to send a `-1` value for ARG. See `C-h i g (emacs) Arguments`

Comment: I just learned something useful from that docstring quote - a zero prefix to swap the items at point and mark, useful for `transpose-word` especially when I write `a and b` then decide `b and a` works better.  :-)  Give and ye shall receive!

Comment: @Ipoik - I probably assumed more Emacs familiarity than I should.  No need to go into the source file - `C-h f transpose-paragraph` will view the doc string from within Emacs.  If you haven't worked through the tutorial yet, I recommend `C-h t` and a couple of hours of learning.  It will pay back much more than the time you spend!

Comment: Well, I found the upper code through C-h f. But I want to bind 2 keys, transpose upwards and transpose downwards . Therefore I was looking for the lisp code.
Still, I can indeed invoke the command with M--1 M-x transp.... but Im looking for the option to BIND a Key, therefore no argument should needed every time of usage.
Indeed iam new to emacs, half year, and I am sad I didn't knew it earlier.

Comment: I was thinking about something like: (global-set-key (kbd "C-M-ü")
    (lambda () (interactive) (transpose-paragraphs -1)))

Problem: I can't push that shortcut several times because the point is at the wrong location.
I need to move it above the paragraph at the end of the script.

Comment: I don't think its a new question.

I want to swap Paragraphs by keybinding. Its working downwards, but not upwards, because the cursor is at the wrong location after the script runs.
Currently 
a
b
c
d

bringing a to the last position works by "transpose-paragraph" bound to M-ü -
Bringing it up again to the first position doesnt. - It indefinitely swaps last two paragraphs due to the wrong position of point/cursor.
I got as far as: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-ü") (lambda () (interactive) (transpose-paragraphs -1)))`

Comment: Works for me (binding to `M-T` as I have no `ü` key here).  `M-T` on paragraph `c` gives `a c b d`, and pressing it again gives `c a b d` as expected.

Comment: I was in fundamental mode - so perhaps there's a problem specific to org-mode (which I don't use myself).

Comment: I am sorry. I cant reproduce what you've said.
I can move A from position 1 to the last one, but not up again.
It indefinitely swaps A and D. 
This issue comes because of the position of my cursor(point).
p.s. Nothing to do with ORG mode. tried fundamental.
It stays under _every_ paragraph, no matter if I switch it up or down.
The other way it should be ABOVE the paragraph I was just switching.

Where is your Point? 
Im sorry for this discussion, and thanks a lot..

Comment: In fundamental mode, I start with paragraphs `aa..bb..c=c..dd.` (with `.` representing newline and `=` representing point), then reverse transpose gives `aa..cc.=.bb..dd.`, and repeating gives `cc.=.aa..bb..dd.` - I do however get wrong results if there's no final newline after `dd` and I try to swap that upwards - too long to describe here, but maybe worth a try yourself.  Do you get different results in fundamental mode and org mode?  I'm using Emacs 24.3, btw.

Comment: emacs 24.5.
same results Org and Fundamental

mine result:
`1) aa..bb..c=c..dd 
2) aa..cc..bb=..dd
3) aa..bb..cc=.dd
4)aa..cc..bb=..dd and so on.`

Can you post your code snippet? - chat possible and just post the result?

Comment: Code snippet?  I just copied yours, but changing the binding: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-T") (lambda () (interactive) (transpose-paragraphs -1)))`.  What I see from your results is not what I see.  I've just tried again, this time starting emacs with `-q --no-site-file` and I still see what I reported above.

Comment: ... I started without my .emacs file and evaluated this codesnippet. same. 
Your point appears BETWEEN the targets, mine UNDER. This results into an endless swappage.
strange behaviour.
by the way, its not a prank ;-)

Why does your point move? There is no code like that in the snippet?
Maybe indeed some version behaviour?

Comment: Sorry, I've now run out of ideas.  I don't know why we see different behaviours.  I'd agree that what you see isn't as useful.

Comment: BTW, you could make a slight improvement by allowing a prefix argument to your function: `(lambda (arg) (interactive "*p") (transpose-paragraphs (- arg)))`.  I've also restricted it to writable buffers (that's what `(interactive "*")` does).

Comment: Somewhat of a workaround, but anyway, Problem solved.
Thanks for your patience! Solution (moves point to right place):

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-ü")
                (lambda () (interactive) (transpose-paragraphs -1)
      (backward-paragraph)
    ))`

Comment: "The workaround arrived at is to `move-paragraph` afterwards:"
did you ment to move the Point? - `backward-paragraph` does move point.